# Beautiful soup returns none data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping the `soup.find()` cannot find the data it returns none here i want to find price
my code is

```
destination = "nepal"
check_in_year = 2022
check_in_month = 12
check_in_day = 13
check_out_year = 2022
check_out_month = 12
check_out_day = 17
adults = 2
total_children = 0
num_rooms = 1
url = "https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQGIAgGoAgO4AqnamocGwAIB0gIkNGEyODNlYTYtYTM2Yi00M2Y3LWE2YjItM2RmYWFlMTM5ZWI22AIF4AIB&sid=44053b754f64b58cfdde1ddc395974a0&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQGIAgGoAgO4AqnamocGwAIB0gIkNGEyODNlYTYtYTM2Yi00M2Y3LWE2YjItM2RmYWFlMTM5ZWI22AIF4AIB%3Bsid%3D44053b754f64b58cfdde1ddc395974a0%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss={}&is_ski_area=0&checkin_year={}&checkin_month={}&checkin_monthday={}&checkout_year={}&checkout_month={}&checkout_monthday={}&group_adults={}&{}&no_rooms={}&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&dest_id=&dest_type=&search_pageview_id=1be740bf37ad0063&search_selected=false".format(
                                  destination,check_in_year,check_in_month,check_in_day,check_out_year,check_out_month,check_out_day,adults,total_children,num_rooms)
print(url)
```

it prints out the url fine and website is also accessed with the same results that i want to search but here's the main content

```
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
links = soup.find("span", {"data-testid":"price-and-discounted-price"})
print(links)
```

it prints out `None`
please help me out with this issue I want to find the price.

Comment: It takes several seconds for that site to respond.  You probably just need to insert a `time.sleep(3)` before fetching the page source.

Comment: i have tried not working @TimRoberts

Comment: If you output the `print(driver.page_source)`, the target tags are not there. So I assume the content is dynamically loaded somehow.

Comment: i used the tags from inspect element but not shown @CharlesHan

Comment: Remember, that page is built dynamically through Javascript.  The stuff you see in the DOM might not be present in the page source.  You need to use the Selenium APIs to fetch from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce the behavior over all requests, but sometimes there is no discounted price shown on the website, what of course could and would happen, cause this website is also testing and delivering content based on behavior or header information like `user-agent` or `device`.

Another szenario could be that you will run into a captcher, so you should inspect your `driver.page_source` respective `soup`.

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

destination = "nepal"
check_in_year = 2022
check_in_month = 12
check_in_day = 13
check_out_year = 2022
check_out_month = 12
check_out_day = 17
adults = 2
total_children = 0
num_rooms = 1
url = "https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQGIAgGoAgO4AqnamocGwAIB0gIkNGEyODNlYTYtYTM2Yi00M2Y3LWE2YjItM2RmYWFlMTM5ZWI22AIF4AIB&sid=44053b754f64b58cfdde1ddc395974a0&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQGIAgGoAgO4AqnamocGwAIB0gIkNGEyODNlYTYtYTM2Yi00M2Y3LWE2YjItM2RmYWFlMTM5ZWI22AIF4AIB%3Bsid%3D44053b754f64b58cfdde1ddc395974a0%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss={}&is_ski_area=0&checkin_year={}&checkin_month={}&checkin_monthday={}&checkout_year={}&checkout_month={}&checkout_monthday={}&group_adults={}&{}&no_rooms={}&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1&dest_id=&dest_type=&search_pageview_id=1be740bf37ad0063&search_selected=false".format(
                                  destination,check_in_year,check_in_month,check_in_day,check_out_year,check_out_month,check_out_day,adults,total_children,num_rooms)
# url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=ultrawide+monitor&crid=R4VD48NS2JN6&sprefix=ultrawide+monitor%2Caps%2C177&ref=nb_sb_noss_1'

driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

First result with find:

```
print(soup.find("span", {"data-testid":"price-and-discounted-price"}))
-> <span aria-hidden="true" class="fcab3ed991 fbd1d3018c e729ed5ab6" data-testid="price-and-discounted-price">€ 42</span>
```

All available in `ResultSet` with `css selectors`:

```
print(soup.select('span[data-testid="price-and-discounted-price"]'))
-> [<span aria-hidden="true" class="fcab3ed991 fbd1d3018c e729ed5ab6" data-testid="price-and-discounted-price">€ 42</span>,
 <span aria-hidden="true" class="fcab3ed991 fbd1d3018c e729ed5ab6" data-testid="price-and-discounted-price">€ 183</span>,
 <span aria-hidden="true" class="fcab3ed991 fbd1d3018c e729ed5ab6" data-testid="price-and-discounted-price">€ 28</span>,...]
```